# Ordering by a generic calculated measure results in infinite recursion? (MDX)

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, ssas-2008

I need to write a calculated measure that would show a share of `Measure1` comparing to the total sum by any given dimension. I managed to do it like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Test] AS
  [Measures].[Measure1] / ( AXIS( 1 ).ITEM( 0 ).DIMENSION.LEVELS( 0 ).ITEM( 0 ), [Measures].[Measure1] )
```

But due to the generic nature of `[Test]`, it is not possible to order a dimension by this measure.

```
SELECT [Measures].[Measure1] ON 0,
ORDER( [Dimension1].MEMBERS, [Measures].[Test] ) ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
```

Executing the above code results in the following error:

> Infinite recursion detected. The loop of dependencies is: Test -> Test.

Which is rather logical — to get `AXIS( 1 ).ITEM( 0 )`, we need a set of dimension members on axis 1, but this set is impossible to obtain until the members are sorted by `[Test]`.

On the other hand, if I define `[Test]` as specific to some dimension, it works as expected:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Test] AS
  [Measures].[Measure1] / ( [Dimension1].[All], [Measures].[Measure1] )
```

It works, because `[Dimension1].[All]` addresses a particular member, without requiring axis 1 to evaluate its member set first.

Is there a way to make this calculated measure generic? Maybe, it's possible to get current dimension's `[All]` member in another way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only displaying one measure, you could rewrite your first query to avoid the error:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Measure1] ON 0,
ORDER([Dimension1].MEMBERS) ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
WHERE ([Measures].[Test])
```

Comment: I thought `ORDER`required a second argument?

Comment: Correct. I cannot remember why I omitted this, three years ago! See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145587.aspx for syntax. I assume the OP wanted to order by [Measures].[Measure1] and use the thi5rd parameter "BASC" too.