# How to correctly replace value of ( [Some Dimension].[All], [Some Measure] )? (MDX, SCOPE())

Tags: scope, ssas, mdx, olap, ssas-2008

I'm using SQL Server Analysis Servises 2008 R2.

I need<sup>1</sup> to replace the value of `[Some Dimension].[All]` when calculated against `[Some Measure]`. Here's what I have tried:

```
SCOPE( [Some Dimension].[All] );
  [Measures].[Some Measure] = 123; // for simplicity sake
END SCOPE;
```

This works as expected when I query against `[Some Dimension]` – the `[All]` member returns `123`, and other members are untouched, showing the actual associated `[Some Measure]` values.

But for some strange reason, all of the members in all other dimensions now return `123` for `[Some Measure]`. I am really lost. Please advice me how to fix this, and why this is happening.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*For the ones who are curious:* the reason I want to replace the value of `[All]` is because `[Some Dimension]` and `[Some Measure]` are related as many-to-many. Because of this, tuple `( [Some Dimension].[All], [Some Measure] )` always returns the total count for `[Some Measure]` in the cube. What I *want* it to return is the count of `[Some Measure]` that are actually associated with at least one member of `[Some Dimension]`</sub>.

Comment: Is it possible that [Some Dimension].[All] is the default member of the dimension, and it is implicitly selected in your queries? That is, when you query ([Measures].[Some Measure],[Some Dimension].[Another Member],[Another Dimension].[Yet Another Member]), do you get 123 or the proper [Measures].[Some Measure] value?

Comment: @SantiagoCepas I guess this is, indeed, the reason. In your example, I'm getting the proper values, but when I change to [Measures].[Some Measure].[All], it's 123 all over again. But how do I fix this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you only want to overwrite [Measures].[Some Measure] when [Some Dimension].[All] is selected, but also when the remaining dimensions' currentmember in your cube is the corresponding "All" member. It that's so, then just changing your scope assignment to SCOPE(Root()) should do the trick.

Comment: @SantiagoCepas Thanks, this answers the question. Well, it still doesn't solve my problem, because an issue from my [other unanswered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408437/) arises again. But if you write your suggestion as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll take a look at your unanswered question, see if something comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want to overwrite `[Measures].[Some Measure]` when `[Some Dimension].[All]` is selected, but also when the remaining dimensions' `currentmember` in your cube is the corresponding "All" member. It that's so, then just changing your scope assignment to `SCOPE(Root())` should do the trick.